# clearInterval on the current element

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project in which I am dynamically generating many `setInterval`'s, and so it is not possible to store their reference in a variable so that it could be used to `clearInterval`. 
    Just wanted to ask you guys if anyone has an idea of how to `clearInterval` on a particular div with an Id.

In my project, when `setInterval` is supposed to be cleared, I am also removing the element from document body. So when `setInterval` is called again, I can put a condition to check if the element with that particular id exists and only then I can execute the `setInterval` code.

Like this,

```
if(document.getElementById("char0") != null)
{
   // execute the setInterval code. 
}
```

But this approach will still take CPU time. I am dynamically generating around 150 setIntervals, not possible to create variable reference for them. Please help if you have any clue of how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to store the interval variable in a closure:

```
var createInterval = function(elementId){
    var interval;
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(document.getElementById(elementId) == null){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }else{
            //Your code
        }
    },1000);
};
```

So you can create any number of intervals what you like and remove it when those DOM elements are gone.

```
createInterval('element1'); 
createInterval('element2');
createInterval('element3');
```

But as what @alexander-omara said, use only few interval to update all elements is better solution in term of CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily keep a reference to a interval ID on a DOM element:

```
var element = document.getElementById("char0");
element._someInterval = setInterval(function(){
    //Some code.
}, 1000);
```

And then clear it using:

```
if(element._someInterval)
{
    clearInterval(element._someInterval);
}
```

However, creating hundreds of intervals does not sound like a very efficient means of doing anything. You way want to create 1 interval, and loop over an array of elements.

Comment: Actually, I am creating a game and in this I have to animate some blocks randomly going up and down the screen, I thought loops would not help solve the purpose as it will move all of them together. Still am thinking if it would be feasible for the kind of effect I want to create. If you have any personal experience on this, please share.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have interval variable to call clearinterval() properly.

If you create variables dynamically like "interval+divid" so each time you get Id, create variable name by this convention and clear the same.

Comment: ya, but setInterval is getting created in a function. To clear Interval the Interval variable should be global. But cannot make global in this way for all variables. any other idea?